# How to equip $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{5\mathbb{Z}}$ with the structure of a $(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{5\mathbb{Z}}[x])/(x^2+1)$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

How to equip $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{5\mathbb{Z}}$ with the structure of a  $(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{5\mathbb{Z}}[x])/(x^2+1)$-module?

I know that $x^2+1=(x-2)(x-3)$ in this field, so that makes it a reducible polynomial. So this makes this unfamiliar to me.

I think I should start by defining the multiplication. For instance, what does $x*1=$?

For $(x-2)(x-3)=0$, I should have that $x=2$ or $x=3$.

Do I just choose one and roll with it?

Comment: Find an endomorphism $\phi$ of $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ that satisfies $\phi^2+\mathrm{id}=0$, where $\phi^2$ means $\phi\circ\phi$

Comment: Think about what it means for a ring R to have an R[x] module structure and then what such an action would look like to factor through a quotient like what you have (as the comment above suggests)

Comment: Yes, as you said, pick one and roll with it. Either $x\cdot1=2$ or $x\cdot1=3$ will work.

Comment: The Chinese Remainder Theorem tells us that $\Bbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^2+1)$ is a direct sum of $\Bbb{Z}_5[x]/(x-2)$ and $\Bbb{Z}_5[x]/(x-3)$. Those are both fields (iso to $\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}$). One component needs to act as zero, and the other "naturally". But you have a choice.